# How to include files embedded in WiX Setup Project itself

Tags: python, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, installation

I have quite a large project that I need to compound from different elements using Wix Toolset.

One of the tasks is to embed Python sources, so they can be automatically installed as well in the installation directory.

How would you do it?

Currently, I just included the wanted Python embedded files into Wix Setup Project itself.

I used heat.exe to harvest all of them and theoretically copy them into installdir.

But for `File` tag I need to specify `Source` argument. What would it be for internal files? Can I actually include the files I want to install in the Setup Project itself? Or they must be coming from an external one?

I hope for your help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

WIX Toolset v3 and v4 offers three different project types

a) MSI Setup
b) Exe-Bootstrapper
c) Libraries / DLLs for Custom Actions

The MSI "copy your exe and dlls" to your system.
The EXE-Bootstrapper will install prerequisites (if needed) and the MSI.
The Custom Actions offer the option that you write VB.NET or C# code to make things which Wix Toolset can not offer.

So, to answer your question, you need a **Wix Toolset Bootstrap Project**. See also [Docu](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/).

[image]
Screenshot of VS2019 with Wix Toolset Extension installed.

Bundle.wxs (Wix Toolset Bootstrapper file)

```xml
  <Bundle>
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage
        Id="MyPreRequ01.exe"
        SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)Prerequisites\python.exe"
        InstallCommand="/foo /bar"
        PerMachine ="yes"
        Permanent ="yes"
        Name ="Python for Win" />
      <MsiPackage ... />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
```

- [Docu ExePackage](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html)
- [Docu MsiPackage](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html)